# SourceTree: stop remember password

Tags: passwords, default

Pulling sources from a repository needs my password.

SourceTree remembers this password by default. I don't want SourceTree to remember my password.
*I have to disable this every time!*

***How can I disable this default behaviour?*** Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Same issue here… SourceTree keep asking me the password (it doesn't even keep it for the session and keep spamming me) and every time it does so, it keeps re-checking the "Remember password" check-box as well. Which, as you said, we inevitably finish by forgetting to uncheck then we manually have to go delete the password in the settings everytime… **TL;DR +1!!**

Answer (score 14):

I use sourcetree un a mac and this help me, it should work the same way in windows:

1. Open the Hosted Repositories window by clicking View > Show Hosted Repositories or Command + Shift + H.
2. Click Edit Accounts
3. Double-click on your account
4. Click Set Password

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I need. I'm sometimes use PC's from customers and don't want to save my pasword at all. The "Remember password" is always checked by default, and then my password is saved at the customer site (when I work quickly and forget to disable the checkbox).

Comment: Use Ctrl+Shift+H on PC.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and finally I found the answer by trial and error.

SourceTree @MacOS

1. SourceTree > Preferences > Network
2. Edit/Delete the Username which you don't want to save
3. Gd luck

Comment: Windows (v 1.6.22.0):

1. Tools > Options > Authentication
2. Same as above

Answer (score 2):

Had the same. In my case it was about duplicated site details. Those two entries were different because one included "http://www." and other not. Removing the longer one helped.

Hope it works for you.

You can check that under tools->options->authentication

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in sourcetree 2.5.
The problem is that I set the permission of `~/.ssh/id_rsa` incorrectly.

`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

will stop sourcetree from asking passwords for every push.
Note that it has to be `600`, otherwise source will ask for passwords.